# Passing names and scores to another form (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class

I am trying to pass user input from my **AddNewStudent** form to my main **StudentScores** form (I click btnAddNew button on my StudentScores form and the AddNewStudent form pops up...I enter my values...then press btnOk button...in hopes of having the values displayed on the StudentScores listbox). However, I am not yet fully familiar with using classes and working with multi form programs, so not only have I been working slower than usual, I have been having a bit of a hard time figuring this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I already have three initialized names and scores that are separated by a | pipe character. I am trying to display any user input in that same format within the StudentScores listbox. I want to have those three names and scores there by default. Thank you for your time.

**My Student class**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My_Program
{
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Scores = new List<int>();


    }

    public Student (string Name, List<int> Scores)
    { this.Name = Name;
        this.Scores = Scores;
    }

    public string Name
    { get;
        set;
    }

    public List<int> Scores
    { get;
      set;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
            string names= this.Name;

            foreach (int myScore in Scores)
            { names += "|" + myScore.ToString();


                }
        return names;
    }

    public int GetscoreTotal()
    { int sum = 0;

        foreach (int score in Scores)
        {
            sum += score;


        }
        return sum;
        }

    public int GetScoreCount()
    { return Scores.Count;
    }

    public void addScore(int Score)
    {
        Scores.Add(Score);
    }
}
}
```

My main form AKA **StudentScores form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace My_Program
{

public partial class StudentScores : Form
{

    //list of students declared
    public List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
    List<Student> Students;

    public StudentScores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


       // listBoxStudents.DataSource = Students;

    }

    private void StudentScore_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //initialized 3 students for list box upon loading program...
        Students = new List<Student>();

        Student student1 = new Student();

        student1.Name = "George Mendoza";
        student1.Scores.Add(97);
        student1.Scores.Add(71);
        student1.Scores.Add(83);
        Students.Add(student1);
        listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student1);

        Student student2 = new Student();

        student2.Name = "John Doe";
        student2.Scores.Add(99);
        student2.Scores.Add(93);
        student2.Scores.Add(97);
        Students.Add(student2);
        listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student2);

        Student student3 = new Student();

        student3.Name = "Bill Cruz";
        student3.Scores.Add(100);
        student3.Scores.Add(100);
        student3.Scores.Add(100);

        Students.Add(student3);
        listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student3);






    }

    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //calls form2 aka AddNewStudent form.
        AddNewStudent frm = new AddNewStudent();
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code something that will delete entries...message box is a start
      DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete your entries?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            while (listBoxStudents.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                listBoxStudents.Items.Remove(listBoxStudents.SelectedItems[0]);

            }
        }
    }

    private void listBoxStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    


    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

**AddNewStudent** form (the form where I add new names and scores and send it to the StudentScores form):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace My_Program
{
public partial class AddNewStudent : Form
{

    List<Student> Students;



    public AddNewStudent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }

    public AddNewStudent (List <Student> Students)
    {
        this.Students = Students;

    }



    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); 
    }

    private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);

        //...

    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);

        if (name == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name before continuing.", "Entry Error.");

        }
        else

        {
           //stuck here...
        }

        }



    }

    private void btnClearScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //clears both the score and scores text box
        txtScore.Text = "";
        txtScores.Text = "";

        txtScore.Focus();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should;

1. Change the access modifiers of the `listBoxStudents` in `StudentScores` to `public`
2. Implement a constructor to the `AddNewStudent` form to accept a `StudentScores` instance. Store the `StudentScores` instance in a field.

   ```
   private StudentScores _studentScoresForm;
   public AddNewStudent(StudentScores studentScoresForm) : this()
   {
     _studentScoresForm = studentScoresForm;
   }

   public AddNewStudent()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
   ```
3. Create the instance of `AddNewStudent` form by passing `this`

   ```
   private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //calls form2 aka AddNewStudent form.
       AddNewStudent frm = new AddNewStudent(this);
       frm.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```

4.In the `AddNewStudent` form, when a change occurs (new student is added) and the OK button is clicked:

```
Student student1 = new Student();
student1.Name = name;
student1.Scores.Add(score);
_studentScoresForm.listBoxStudents.Add(student1);
```

Comment: I followed your advice, however, the AddNewStudent form is now blank during run time after clicking the btnAddNew button. Once I remove "this" from step number 3, the dialog box reappears.

Comment: Editing it to invoke default constructor.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. InitializeComponent() should be invoked to initialize controls on the form.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help. It has fixed the blank form error. For step 4, would you do that within the okay button method?

Comment: Yes, when an action has been taken and OK is clicked any updates to the list should be reflected to the students list box and the add student form then may be closed

Comment: I have an updated okay button method to post, but I am not sure if I should post it here in the comment section or as an answer. My other question is, how would I implement the line of code in step four within the okay button method? That is the only part I need to understand the whole process. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just copy that code to your question please. I can then copy and modify that

Comment: I just updated my post (modified the btnOk_Click method within the AddNewStudent form).

Answer (score 0):

As *@Oguz* has already explained, you want to pass the `StudentScores` form as a variable to the `AddNewStudent` form.

This will let you access any public attribute in the `StudentScores` form from the `AddNewStudent` form. In other words, you can access the original student list and add a new student to it. Only the variable reference of `StudentScores` form is passed so all changes are reflected in the original student list.

Answer (score 0):

In the AddNewStudent form this constructor will never be called :

```
    public AddNewStudent (List <Student> Students)
{
    this.Students = Students;
}
```

So I think what you want to do is use it instead and change this :

```
   private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //calls form2 aka AddNewStudent form.
    AddNewStudent frm = new AddNewStudent();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

to this:

```
   private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //calls form2 aka AddNewStudent form.
    AddNewStudent frm = new AddNewStudent(Students);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

And now you pass your list of students to the form where you can make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

The most professional way of doing this is using delegates

In the AddNewstudent form create a delegate with four parameters that are required

```
public delegate void PassControl(string a,int b,int c,int d);
public PassControl passControl;
```

On Click of OK button in AddNewStudent form

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (passControl != null)
            {
                passControl(txtName.Text,int.Parse(txt1.Text),int.Parse(txt2.Text),int.Parse(txt3.Text));
            }
        }
```

In Student Scores Form on click of Add New Button

```
  private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //calls form2 aka AddNewStudent form.
            AddNewStudent frm = new AddNewStudent();
            frm.passControl = new C2.PassControl(this.PassData);
            frm.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Write a delegate function  in Student Scores form to which it points to.

```
  private void PassData(string a,int b,int c,int d)
        {

            Student student1 = new Student();

            student1.Name = a;
            student1.Scores.Add(b);
            student1.Scores.Add(c);
            student1.Scores.Add(d);
            Students.Add(student1);
            listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student1);
        }
```

Comment: How would one go about this using the code I provided above? I have not use/learned of delegates yet.

Comment: So learn delegates first ..Then you would figure out the advantages of it...Well I have shown another way to do it..That's It...